# Is it possible to post to a users feed with a share action link?

Tags: facebook

I've noticed sometimes there's a share link on some things in my feed. Is it possible to post to a users wall and attach an action link that has a share option that would create a share dialogue directly on the users feed? Something like this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: "feed",
    name: 'sometitle',
    caption: 'somecaption',
    description: 'some description',
    link: 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/1234?sk=app_234123123',
    picture: 'http://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico',
    actions: [{
        name: 'share',
        link: '????'
        }]
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an outstanding FB issue.

Here's the FB bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164888633588257

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. From the document, only the following option accepted : message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source.

I think it's easier to put some javascript in the target page(link), which call the share api seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Hoang isn't quite correct. You can create a share link, but it is a bit hobbled. Within your actions array, you should have a name of 'share' and a link as shown here:

`$attachment['actions'] = array('name'=>'Share', 'link'=>"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=". urlencode($href))`

While this won't pop up a native dialog box, it will give you some semblance of the share functionality.

Comment: Why is that normal status updates come with a "Share" link and updates that include "link" or "picture" do not? Seems like more of a privacy setting than anything else.

When I create a "Link" from Facebook itself, it gets shared with a "Share" link available.

Comment: How do you know the `$href` if you did not POST the story on Facebook yet? I would say it's not possible. Plus the actions links are reserved for Open Graph actions. All actions of an app need to be reviewed and approved by Facebook.

Comment: @Bradley it's a facebook policy issue, which I believe has since been reverted.

Comment: @maxwell2022 As I just said, this is no longer the case. Either way, the link isn't to the facebook post, it's to the page you are linking to.