# Is It Possible To Have Multiple Attachments In A Facebook Feed Dialog Call?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I currently am developing a Magento driven online store which allows for a user to share a product on Facebook and get the opinion of others. It works quite well for sharing one product, however I also a comparison feature on the site which allows a user to choose a few products and then compare them. I would like the ability for a user to share all of the products they're considering and get the opinion of their Facebook friends.

Is it possible to have multiple attachments when posting to a Facebook users wall through the Facebook feed dialog, if so, could someone please point me to the appropriate location.

Here is the current code I am using to share a product with one attachment.

```
function post_to_fb()
{
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'stream.publish',
        attachment: {
            name: '<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>',
            description: (
                '<?php echo $_product->getShortDescription() ?>'
            ),
            source: '<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init(Mage::registry('current_product'), 'small_image')->resize(100,100);?>',
            href: '<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() ?>'
             },
             action_links: [
             { text: 'View the Product', href: '<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() ?>' }
             ],
              user_prompt_message: 'Personal message here'
             },
                 function(response) {
                     if (response && response.post_id) {
                         alert('Post was published.');
                     } else {
                         alert('Post was not published.');
                     }
                 }
             ); 
          }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand with "multiple attachments. You mean the multiple pictures or multiple links?

Comment: What I mean is when you open up the feed dialog and you have the area to write a message, then underneath you have a name and description as well as a link and image, is it possible to have multiple items beneath with a name and description encased in the attachment:{} section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not long ago, I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356421/is-it-possible-to-post-to-a-users-feed-with-a-share-action-link/7357132#7357132). It's about customizing the feed posted to Facebook, and the answer is no.

But Facebook just pull out lots of changes, including some changes in posting feed. I have noticed the new "properties" params. Though document is not clear, you can test your luck with the "properties" in the [document about FB.ui here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

Comment: I can't for the life of me get properties to work. Any chance you can post some examples of the properties argument in use? Especially for multiple links. That would be very appreciated.

Comment: I worked it out in the end. Turns out properties has to sit INSIDE of attachments: []